# Problems with installing Ruby Gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-mavericks

I have Ruby installed on my Mac, but when I try `gem install rails` I get the following error message:

```
Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ENOMEM: Cannot allocate memory - connect(2) (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

I've tried several other gems and get the same message. I'm not sure what this means, can anyone suggest anything?

Output of `gem env`:

> RubyGems Environment:
>
> - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
> - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
> - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
> - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
> - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
> - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
>
>   - ruby
>   - universal-darwin-13
> - GEM PATHS:
>
>   - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
>   - /Users/brent/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
>   - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/
>       2.0.0
> - GEM CONFIGURATION:
>
>   - :update_sources => true
>   - :verbose => true
>   - :backtrace => false
>   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
> - REMOTE SOURCES:
>
>   - https://rubygems.org/

Comment: Also...  I checked my gem install and it's up-to-date.  just FYI

Comment: Run `gem env` at the command-line and add its output to your question by editing it.

Comment: It says you're out of memory. _Are_ you out of memory?

Comment: I am seeing this same problem too and have no idea what is wrong. At best this is a really poor error message; my system is **not** out of memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem, and it was due to Norton Firewall.  Apparently, the firewall is never prompting for application blocking when sudo is called in this way.  Consequently, the network access is blocked.  Temporarily disabling the firewall fixed the error.

This also may explain why other solutions work, including other terminal apps-- they may have been previously granted network access.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "Ruby" isn't installed or working properly.

I recommend using "[RVM (Ruby Version Manager)](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)", but, if you need to go the other way, then make sure Ruby is installed in your system. List your gems and grep for Ruby. Then install Rails.

I'm assuming other stuff like bundler or permissions are going to be dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use system ruby. You're going to need to install a ruby-manager like RVM or rbenv.

I really like this *shell script* from *thoughtbot* -  https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop

You're going to have to install Xcode and the additional developer tools and command-line tools from Xcode.

Afterward run the thoughtbot script. It will take a while once you get it going. So go make some coffee. This will install homebrew, rbenv and setup everything.

Comment: This is a really heavyweight solution to fix a ruby installation problem.

Comment: Have you never installed ruby before @kevin? I think what I presented is super simple compared to how I used to have to do it.. Idk welcome to rails! Its easy, right!? Compared to rocket science anyways

Comment: Also, Thoughtbot didn't resolve the issue. I still get the same error when trying to run `gem install compass`. By the way, this is on Mavericks.

Comment: @kevin I am using mavericks as well. When you check the ruby version when running ruby -v what do you get? Did you restart your terminal session?

Comment: Also after restarting terminal it should load your new bash_profile zsh. Run 'rbenv --help' to list the commands. For instance, you can use the command 'rbenv versions' to see what's available on the machine. Or to install 'rbenv install 2.0.0-p195' and then to set the ruby version globally you can use 'rbenv global 2.0.0-p195'

Comment: Also double check that you installed the command-line tools in Xcode. You'll have to google where that's located in Xcode so you can download it. They changed the location on mavericks, and after the update I ended up having  to re-download and re-enable it. It threw errors at me

Answer (score 0):

Since there seems to be no working answer, if you guys are still stuck with the issue, I suggest the following workaround (which works for me on OS X Mavericks):
1) This seems to be a Terminal related issue. 
2) Therefore, please try your commands ("gem install rails" or "gem install compass") in an iTerm2 (http://www.iterm2.com) console.

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same error and it was my network that was causing the error. Check your network connections and proxy settings.

Answer (score -2):

You should **really** use [Bundler](http://bundler.io).

"[test-rails](https://github.com/dliggat/test-rails)" is an example of a really simple Rails app that installs the Rails gem via bundler.

You don't need to have Rails installed as a system-level gem. Save yourself the future headache and start right away with Bundler - you won't regret it.

Comment: This question didn't ask for your opinion on bundler and that in no way helped to solve this problem.